# Failed to customize Java Version in Bluemix

Tags: java, ibm-cloud

I've deployed my app to Bluemix and want to change the default Java version from 8 to 7. Then I run the cf command "cf set-env myapp JBP_CONFIG_IBMJDK "version: 1.7+"", then run "cf restage myapp", but error occurred. Below is the log.

Anyone can give me some tips on how to customize Java version, instead of using the default one? Thanks so much!

```
Updated app with guid 978e8006-6211-47c7-aa67-2931be310519 ({"environment_json"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN"})
Got staging request for app with id 978e8006-6211-47c7-aa67-2931be310519

-----> Downloaded app package (12M)

-----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (4.0K)

-----> Liberty Buildpack Version: v2.3-20151208-1311

E, [2016-01-10T09:42:28.093168 #73] ERROR -- /var/vcap/data/dea_next/admin_buildpacks/24690e4f-31f1-4172-b295-80c16598b357_bb01df5b768b9bb0430b0a8427293feda0a920cc/lib/liberty_buildpack/buildpack.rb:50:in `rescue in drive_buildpack_with_logger': Compile failed with exception #<NoMethodError: undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass>

undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass

Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed

encountered error: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid 978e8006-6211-47c7-aa67-2931be310519
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is related with the buildpack not compiling successfully. 
Check if you are using any feature related to jre 1.8 version.
All the options to configure the jre used in your liberty application are documented here:
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/liberty/index.html#liberty

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 
My app uses JDK 1.7 to compile, and it can be deployed in my local Liberty with JDK 1.7 specified successfully. So I think I probably don't use any features related to jre 1.8.